# CUDA on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cuda

I am installing CUDA from [this link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal).

Though it is a CUDA SDK 9.2, when I check the version installed using nvcc --version, I get the following results:

**nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17**

I am new to CUDA and wanted to check if this is expected. Should I expect 9.2 as the CUDA version post installation?
FYI - GPU is GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

Comment: You obviously also have CUDA 7.5 installed somewhere. Did you have an actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the official guide step by step，click [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) to check if the toolkit is installed correctly. Also,the post-installation-actions must be taken into consideration,click [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions) to get more info.

I had occured the same condition u mention above, In my case, I add this path to the PATH:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

The best solution should be to modify the corresponding profile file, like this:

```
vim /etc/profile
Add export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}} to the end of the file
reboot
```

Good Luck.